Does Vampiric Cataclysm's healing apply to repeated attacks from Aspect of Momus?
The Daedalus Hammer upgrade Vampiric Cataclysm for the Witch's Staff has the effect

After you slay a foe with your Omega Attack, restore 5
health.

The Aspect of Momus for the Witch's Staff has the effect

Whenever you use Omega Moves each fires in place up to 3 times until you use it again.

If I pick up Vampiric Cataclysm while using the Aspect of Momus, then use my Omega attack, will the extra "fired in place" Omega Attacks also restore 5 health if they kill an enemy?
